# How to use a json data for socket emit from client side?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, sockets

What is the best method to use a mysql fetched data during socket emiting time?
For example, I will have a data retrieved from database and now I would like to use that data on `socket.emit('emit_name', function(data){ })`.What will be the best way?

I firstly, tested with easy way to find if it works or not rather then diving beginning into complicated one from json.I used two data as 'type' and 'fruit' something like this on "Client side"

```
var socket = io.connect( 'http://localhost:8080' );
var nameVal = "Type";
var msg = "apple";

socket.emit( 'messages', { type : nameVal, fruit: msg } );
```

on Server side

```
var socket = require( 'socket.io' );
var express = require( 'express' );
var http = require( 'http' );
var app = express();
var mysql = require('mysql');
var server = http.createServer( app );
var io = socket.listen( server );
var pool = mysql.createPool({
connectionLimit : 10,
host: "localhost",
user: "root",
password: "",
database: "mydb"
  }
);


io.sockets.on( 'connection', function() {

console.log( "User connected..!" );

io.client.on( 'messages', function(data) {
console.log( 'Message received ' + data.type + ":" + data.fruit );

  });

});

server.listen(8080);
```

After doing this all I just started my node server and I get "connected" on my socket on page load but my work on socket side isn't working at all as I wised.The result(problem) on socket part of server side gives this error as below image :-

[image]

What might be the problem?How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is just wrong:

```
io.sockets.on( 'connection', function() {

console.log( "User connected..!" );

io.client.on( 'messages', function(data) {
console.log( 'Message received ' + data.type + ":" + data.fruit );

  });

});
```

It should be this:

```
io.on( 'connection', function(socket) {

    console.log( "User connected..!" );

    socket.on( 'messages', function(data) {
        console.log( 'Message received ' + data.type + ":" + data.fruit );
    });
});
```

You have to use the `socket` variable that is passed to the `io.on('connection`, ...)` event to set event handlers on the newly connected socket.

---

In addition, this line of your client code:

```
socket.emit( 'messages', { type : nameVal, fruit: msg } );
```

may be running too soon before the socket has finished connecting.  `io.connect()` is asynchronous.  It does not complete immediately.  If you try to send data before it is connected, then there is not yet a live socket to actually send the data on.  It's possible that socket.io will cache that data until the socket connects (you'd have to check the socket.io code to see for sure), but it is much safer to wait for the `connect` event on the socket before sending data.

Comment: Sir you are great! It worked perfect for me! By your solution I could now work with json type data also which was I mainly planned to mix up with socket :)